# Playwright teardown ONLY if all specs have passed

Tags: playwright, teardown

How do I run teardown in Playwright JS only if all my specs have passed?

As you can see from my setup, I turned off the parallel run and I am organising my tests in a list via test.list.js. That runs all fine and actually the teardown run every time after all my tests run BUT the problem is that teardown runs irrespective of test passing or failing. I would like it to exclude the teardown if there any is failure found.

```js
 projects: [
    {
      name: 'setup',
      testMatch: 'test.list.js',
      teardown: 'myTeardown'
    },
    {
      name: 'myTeardown',
      testMatch: /destroy\.all\.js/,
      use: {
        ...devices['Desktop Chrome'],
        headless: false
    },
    },
    {
      name: 'chromium',
      use: {
         ...devices['Desktop Chrome'],
         headless: false,
         dependencies: ['setup']
     },
    },
```

Comment: what about checking TestResult in the teardown?

Comment: @szogoon This would make sense to check the result for either pass or fail within some form of IF statement. Do you have any example where the Playwright is directly working with test results post run?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: THIS WILL NOT WORK AS THE TEST RESULTS ARE NOT AVAILABLE TO TESTINFO UNTIL AFTER TEARDOWN HAS COMPLETED.  LOOKING FOR SOLUTION :)

You should be able to get that from the testinfo fixture in project dependency teardown I believe:

```
// tests/dependencies/setup.ts

import { test as setup} from '@playwright/test';

setup('basic test setup', async ({}) => {
  // do something
});
```

```
// tests/dependencies/teardown.ts

import { test as teardown } from '@playwright/test';

teardown('basic test teardown', async ({}, testInfo) => {
  if (testInfo.errors.length === 0) {
    // teardown code here
  }
});
```

```
// playwright.config.ts

projects: [
    {
      name: "setup",
      testMatch: "tests/depedencies/setup.ts",
      teardown: "teardown",
    },
    {
      name: "teardown",
      testMatch: "tests/depedencies/teardown.ts",
    },
    {
      name: "chromium",
      use: { ...devices["Desktop Chrome"] },
      dependencies: ["setup"],
    },
  ],
```

Comment: Cheers for that, that only works if its directly in a test but can I somehow make it from a config file like a global-teardown.js ?

Comment: I could be wrong, but the [documentation](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-global-setup-teardown#option-2-configure-globalsetup-and-globalteardown) states:

"Using globalSetup and globalTeardown will not produce traces or artifacts. If you want to produce traces and artifacts, use project dependencies."

By `artifacts`, I think that also includes access to testInfo, so as it says, it you want it, you'll have to use project dependencies like in my example.  

Is there any reason you can't use that?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use that? Yes - it looks like the if statement is ignored and it executed the code inside of it anyway even if there are errors :-(

Comment: @DavidPongo Actually, that does make sense thinking about it, because the teardown is a still a part of the test run and the test report / run won't be complete until after teardown has run in this instance.  This is an interesting problem....I'll give is some thought as I'm intrigued on how to fix it :)